# where is hdfs /user space allocated in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am confused where is hdfs /user space allocated. It is not visible from Linux file system. But there is a directory called /user in hdfs. I guess it is from configuration? Is it created across all the nodes in the cluster?

```
% hadoop fs -mkdir books
% hadoop fs -ls .
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x - tom supergroup 0 2009-04-02 22:41 /user/tom/books
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom supergroup 118 2009-04-02 22:29 /user/tom/quangle.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have read that HDFS is a distributed filesystem runs on top of a filesystem like ext3,4, xfs etc. If you use linux ls command you won't be able to see the files. HDFS has two parts HDFS metadata dir(name dir) and data dir. When you create a directory an entry will be added to HDFS metadata which is a file (fsimage) the same is located in hdfs namenode dir. In case of a file an entry will be added to HDFS metadata and underlying data would be stored in different slave nodes as blocks and metadata contains the pointer to these blocks.

In HDFS, metadata is centralized means HDFS metadata will be stored only on namenode server(Usually one server if HA enabled two servers will be there ). Whereas the underlying data will be stored as distributed.

You have a option for viewing the contents of fsimage( HDFS metadata) file, HDFS provides a utility oiv (offline image view) which can be used to view the contents of fsimage file

```
Usage : hdfs oiv -i Fsimage_File -o output_file
```

Comment: Where is that ext3,4 file system located? That shoud be visible correct?

Comment: That's linux native filesystem, won't get anything from there, you better try to locate your fsimage file and read the same using oiv so that you will get an idea about what a filesystem is ? 
It should be there in the directory which is specified in your hdfs-site.xml as dfs.name.dir or dfs.namenode.name.dir value.

Comment: dfs.namenode.name.dir is file:///dfs/nn in my hdfs-site.xml. So hdfs file system is capped by the file system size where /df/nn is located ? Does /dfs/nn only  hold metadata?  Where is data actually located? I can't find it from hdfs-site.xml.

Comment: oiv doesn't tell anything. hdfs oiv -i /dfs/nn/current/fsimage_0000000000000020462
15/02/21 10:22:10 INFO offlineImageViewer.WebImageViewer: WebImageViewer started. Listening on /127.0.0.1:5978. Press Ctrl+C to stop the viewer.

Comment: The HDFS data itself is stored under the local directory specified in the `dfs.datanode.data.dir` property in your `hdfs-site.xml`, but remember that you won't just be able to see your original files as-is there because HDFS doesn't store it that way.